# Please Explain the Difference between these two Codes

Tags: python

Code 1

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
tri = nums
nums.append(4)
print(tri)       //this prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Code 2

```
num = 9
num2 = num
num = 12
print num2       // this prints 9 **BUT I expected 12 like abouve code**
```

My Ques is Why there is a Difference between these two outputs when the the Procedure and Assignments are almost Similar ?

Comment: I tried to make this code Visible just like you did.. but I failed :( Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was too snarky; I see what your problem is now, and am posting an answer.

Comment: Related read: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @delnan : Great! I just read that article on HAckerNews and played with it

Thanks

Comment: @MohitAphale The key distinction from that article: **rebinding the name** (eg, `num = 12`) vs. **mutating the value** (eg, `nums.append(4)`).

Comment: [Useful visualization](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=nums+%3D+%5B1,+2,+3%5D%0Atri+%3D+nums%0Anums.append(4)%0Aprint+tri%0A%0Anum+%3D+9%0Anum2+%3D+num%0Anum+%3D+12%0Aprint+num2&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, `nums` and `tri` refer the same object. The `append` method modifies the reference object in place, so both `nums` and `tri` continue to refer to the same (modified) object.

In your second example, `num` is set to a completely new object (12); `num2` continues to refer to the object (9) that `num` referred to before you changed its value.

Comment: Note that in the second example, `nums` and `tri` did refer to the same object (after `tri = nums`), if only temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

nums is a list, so it is copied by reference and the num is copied by value.

you can use `tri = nums[:]` to copy the nums by value

Answer (score -1):

Code 1 your using Tuple. Tuples are **reference** type Data. (Arrays, Tuple, Class)

Code 2 is Your using Integer. It's **Value** Type Data.

Value Type always copy value to another memory location.

But Reference data type always Replace value to memory location.

This Concept comes with Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: **-1** `assert type(tri) is tuple` -  `AssertionError`

Comment: And in python, `int`s are also reference types